# Javascript assignment for school involving objects and Validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation

the past two days I've been really struggling on finishing this assignment.
The assignment goal is to create a javascript that takes in Student information until the user either hits cancel or enters in blank text. 
the information gets validated every time the user enters information if it is valid, it is then saved to a Student Object Array.
Here is my code:

```
var Student =[];
// Validates Student Courses, loops through making sure they are equal to courseList values.
function validateCourses(courses){
   var valid='';
   var courseList = ['APC100','IPC144','ULI101','IOS110','EAC150','IBC233','OOP244','DBS201','INT222'];
     alert(courses);
       for(var i =0;i<courseList.length;i++){
          var a = courses;
          a.splice();
             if(a[i]!==courseList[i]){
             valid=false;
            }
            else{
               valid=true;
            }
       }
   return valid;
}
function formatingName(name){
   var res ='',cap='';
      res = res + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
      cap = res + name.substr(1);
   return cap;
}
// I'm having issues with this validation for the student id. the student id can only be xxx.xxx.xxx
function validateStudentID(sid){
   var validate=0;
   var patt1 = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([.]?)([0-9]{3})?([.]?)([0-9]{2})$/;
   var result = patt1.test(sid);
   return result;
}
var courseSelect=[];
var tag=0;
// this displays what users are in what course depending on what the user enters
function code(coursecode){
      for(var w = 0;w<count;w++){
         for(var t = 0;t<Student[w].courses.length;t++){
             var a = Student[w].courses;
             a.splice();
            if(a[t] == coursecode){
               tag=1;
            }
         }
         if(tag){
             courseSelect.push(Student[w].fname + " " + Student[w].lname + " " + Student[w].id + " " + Student[w].email);
         }
      }

   alert('List students registered in ' + coursecode + ' :\n\n' + courseSelect.join('\n'));
}
// main functions and validation calls
var userInput = "";
var i=0,count=0,j=4,flag=false;
var result='',courses=[];
var Student,validCourses;
do{

   userInput = prompt("Please enter first name, last name,student ID,\n" +
                     "email and courses (speareted by ',').");
 if(userInput != null && userInput !=''){
      result = userInput.split(',');
         for(var i=4;i<result.length && i < 10;i++){
             courses.push(result[i].toUpperCase());
         } 
       // VALIDATION OF STUDENT ID AND STUDENT COURSES */
     while(!flag){
       var valid = validateStudentID(result[2]);
         alert(valid);
          if(valid){
            id = result[2];
            flag=true;
         }
         else {
            alert(Student.id + " is not valid Student ID!" + "\n" + "Please try again.");
            flag=false;
         }
         validCourse = validateCourses(courses);
         if(validCourse){
           flag=true;
         }
        else {
          alert( validCourse + " is not the course provided by the CPD program! \n Please try again");
          flag=false;
        }
     }
        if(flag){
           Student.push({
            fname:formatingName(result[0]),
            lname:formatingName(result[1]),
            id:result[2],
            email:result[3].toLowerCase(),
              courses:courses,
           });

         count++;
         i++;
        }
        else {
           Student = [];
        }
 }
}while(userInput != null && userInput !='');
alert('There are total '+ count + ' students registered');
var coursecode = prompt("Please enter course code: ");
code(coursecode);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most obvious problems in your code are:

- You have a `while(!flag)` loop after the input section. That loop contains no other request to input anything. Therefore it will run endlessly if your `validate*` methods return `false`.
- Your regular expression `/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([.]?)([0-9]{3})?([.]?)([0-9]{2})$/` isn't doing what you want it to do. You can simplify it to just `/^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$/` as all you want to know is whether your input parameter `sid` contains three number blocks, each of length 3. You don't need any braces for that and escaping them via `\(?` would anyways be wrong. You also didn't escape your points via `\.`, which is wrong as they would match basically any character. You should read up more about regular expressions.
- Your loop in `validateCourses` looks wrong. Why do you assign `courses` to a new variable (it isn't copied to `a`) and then call `splice()`? Your following `if` condition is also wrong, as it assumes that `a` and `courseList` have equal length and that the positions of the courses would match. That's certainly not what you want. You should check for each course in `course` whether it is contained in `courseList`, e.g.: `var notInCourseList = courses.filter(function(course) { return (courseList.indexOf(course) == -1); });` and then `return (notInCourseList.length == 0);`. A `forEach` loop would be an easy alternative. You should read some tutorials about that.
- Similarly, I don't see any good reason for `var a = Student[w].courses; a.splice();` in `code()`. Just check directly on `Student[w].courses`.

Slightly more working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8apoc2vk/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! This is my intro class to the web, I'm just getting the hang of it, thanks for baring with me!  I've fixed my code according to your advice. 
I am having an issue however with after an invalid course being entered I am unable to renter a valid course when prompt again. is that because of my validation in my main?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, i seem to be able to enter multiple courses in the jsfiddle. Depending on how exactly you changed your code, you might have to add a `flag = false;` right after the `do {` (before the prompt), otherwise the flag/result of the last validation might be reused incorrectly.